# Extract filename with extension from url

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the filename from a url. and I came up with this regex

```
(\w+)(\.\w+)+(?!.*(\w+)(\.\w+)+)
```

it works fine with a case like this one

```
http://www.example.com/bar/baz/filename.jpeg?testing
```

but not this one (it should return file-name.jpeg)

```
http://www.example.com/bar/baz/file-name.jpeg?testing
```

thank you for your help

Comment: it's also capturing the domain

Comment: What's your actual goal? There's no guarantee that a URI containing "filename.jpeg" will actually give you a JPEG image...

Comment: it doesn't matter I just need the filename with the extension www.example.com/test.exe?bad=true I want to extract test.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
([\w-]+)(\.[\w-]+)+(?!.*\/)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XIzCbk/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `([\w-]+)`: Match 1+ of word or - characters
- `(\.[\w-]+)+`: 1 or more parts after dot
- `(?!.*\/)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a `/` after this match